# Properly displaying pyplot scatter plot with X/Y histograms and a colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, scatter-plot, colorbar

I saw this [tutorial on how to make a scatter plot with a histogram for the x and y axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_hist.html) and I thought it would be neat to also tack on a colorbar for an extra dimension of information. To do this, I utilized "the make_axes_locatable" function, like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
# generating fake data
tx = np.random.randn(1000)
ty = np.random.randn(1000)
tz = np.random.randn(1000)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 2,  width_ratios=(4, 1), height_ratios=(1, 4),
                      left=0.1, right=0.9, bottom=0.1, top=0.9,
                      wspace=0.05, hspace=0.05)
# Create the Axes.
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax_histx = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], sharex=ax)
ax_histy = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1], sharey=ax)


def scatter_hist_and_colorbar(x, y, c, ax, ax_histx, ax_histy,label):
    # no labels
    ax_histx.tick_params(axis="x", labelbottom=False)
    ax_histy.tick_params(axis="y", labelleft=False)

    # the scatter plot:
    sc=ax.scatter(x,y,marker='o',label=label,c=c)

    # now determine nice limits by hand:
    binwidth = 0.25        
    xlim = (int(np.max(np.abs(x))/binwidth) + 1) * binwidth
    ylim = (int(np.max(np.abs(y))/binwidth) + 1) * binwidth
           

    xbins = np.arange(-xlim, xlim + binwidth, binwidth)
    ybins = np.arange(-ylim, ylim + binwidth, binwidth)    
    ax_histx.hist(x, bins=xbins)
    ax_histy.hist(y, bins=ybins, orientation='horizontal')
    
    
    return sc
    
sc1= scatter_hist_and_colorbar(tx,ty,tz, ax, ax_histx, ax_histy,label='data')
ax.set_ylabel('x data')
ax.set_xlabel('y data')
ax.legend()


divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('left', size='5%', pad=1)
cbar=fig.colorbar(sc1, cax=cax, orientation='vertical')
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('z data',rotation=90,labelpad=5)
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("left")
plt.savefig('example.png')
plt.show()][2]][2]
```

This almost works except the "ax_histx" axis is now stretched and doesn't properly line up due to the addition of the colorbar. Is there a way to resize the "ax_histx" axis or is there a better way to add a colorbar to the "ax" subplot so that it wouldn't affect the "ax_histx" or "ax_histy" axes?

[image: example]

Comment: How about a grid with two rows and three columns, with xhist as the second row, color bar as the first row, scatter plots as the second row, and yhist as the third row? `cax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])`

Comment: @r-beginners, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are you suggesting making a 2x2 plot grid with a colorbar as its own axis? I think, I can work with that. I'll make an edit with a solution. Thanks!

Comment: My suggestion was meant to be a configuration of `row1:None|hist|None,row2:cax|scatter|hist`. I think your approach is also excellent.

Answer (score 0):

After getting a suggestion form @r-beginners , I tried tweaking this code to place a colorbar in the upper right, perpendicular to the histogram axes. This way, it doesn't distort the width/heights of the other shared axes:

```
# some random data
tx = np.random.randn(1000)
ty = np.random.randn(1000)
tz = np.random.randn(1000)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 2,  width_ratios=(4, 1), height_ratios=(1, 4),
                      left=0.1, right=0.9, bottom=0.1, top=0.9,
                      wspace=0.05, hspace=0.05)
# Create the Axes.
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax_histx = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0], sharex=ax)
ax_histy = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1], sharey=ax)


def scatter_hist_and_colorbar(x, y, c, ax, ax_histx, ax_histy,label):
    # no labels
    ax_histx.tick_params(axis="x", labelbottom=False)
    ax_histy.tick_params(axis="y", labelleft=False)

    # the scatter plot:
    sc=ax.scatter(x,y,marker='o',label=label,c=c)

    # now determine nice limits by hand:
    binwidth = 0.25
    xymax = max(np.max(np.abs(x)), np.max(np.abs(y)))
    lim = (int(xymax/binwidth) + 1) * binwidth
    
    xlim = (int(np.max(np.abs(x))/binwidth) + 1) * binwidth
    ylim = (int(np.max(np.abs(y))/binwidth) + 1) * binwidth
           

    xbins = np.arange(-xlim, xlim + binwidth, binwidth)
    ybins = np.arange(-ylim, ylim + binwidth, binwidth)    
    ax_histx.hist(x, bins=xbins)
    ax_histy.hist(y, bins=ybins, orientation='horizontal')
    
    
    return sc
    
sc1= scatter_hist_and_colorbar(tx,ty,tz, ax, ax_histx, ax_histy,label='data')
ax.set_ylabel('x data')
ax.set_xlabel('y data')
ax.legend()


divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)


divider = make_axes_locatable(ax0)
ca = divider.append_axes('left', size='50%')
ax0.axis('off')


cbar=fig.colorbar(sc1, cax=ca, orientation='vertical')
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('z data',rotation=270,labelpad=5)
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")

gs.tight_layout(fig,pad=1)
plt.savefig('example.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: example]